# WPF : Binding to a listbox, special behavior when nothing is selected

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a window with a listbox, and a usercontrol details 'view' that is bound to the selected item of the listbox. By default, nothing is selected in the listbox (this is default behavior as far as I know, nothing special here).

What I'd like to do is have some sort of message appear (instead of, but in the same place as the details view) when nothing is selected in the Listbox.

Here is the code, I've been trying to condense this as small as I can and so have removed most of the MVVM/ ViewModel /NotifyPropertyChanged stuff.

I'll start with the window :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Name="ListList"></ListBox>
    <view:BoundItem Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ListList, Path=SelectedItem}" ></view:BoundItem>        
</Grid>
```

The item that gets bound to does nothing more than echo some properties :

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Foo, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Bar, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Baz, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And I'm setting populating the listbox and defining a dataitem all in one go :

```
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for ListBoxSelectedItemBinding.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ListBoxSelectedItemBinding : Window
{
    public ListBoxSelectedItemBinding()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ListList.Items.Add(new ListBoxData());
        this.ListList.Items.Add(new ListBoxData());
        this.ListList.Items.Add(new ListBoxData());

    }
}

public class ListBoxData
{
    public string Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return "Foo";
        }
    }

    public string Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return "FooBar";
        }
    }

    public string Baz
    {
        get
        {
            return "FooBarBaz";
        }
    }
}
```

When the app starts up, nothing is selected, and I see the listbox on the Left, and 3 empty textboxes on the right. Once I select something, the three textboxes get populated.

What I'd like is to just hide the  completely until something gets selected. I think I can give a default item to bind to with Binding TargetNullValue or FallBackValue - That isn't quite what I am looking for. More so, I'm looking to entirely hide the  and replace it with something else (suppose a button, just to give an idea).

I don't think there is anything at all complicated here. I've searched for answers, but am just swamped with slightly related subjects on listbox binding, selected item, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deal with **Visibility** property and hide one Panel when SelectedItem equals null and simultaneously show latter.

Hide TextBoxes Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ListList, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <TextBox/>
    <TextBox/>
    <TextBox/>
</Grid>
```

and Show your Buttons Grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ListList, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <Button/>
    <Button/>
    <Button/>
</Grid>
```

Keep in mind they need to be place at the same place (for instance the same column and row). 
 More sofisticated way out then dealing with Visibility is to use **ContentControl** which will automatically change View based on ViewModel change. More [here](http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/).

Comment: Thanks - in my case, the boundItem is defined in another file (usercontrol). The ListBox named == ListList is out of scope. Is there a way to expose this from the usercontrol?

Comment: And, an edit to the edit. 5 minutes is not enough time to fix comments. Binding to the ElementName, from a separate user control, does not work.  Instead I just Checked if the value of {Binding} was x:Null, and that has does what I need it to.

Comment: If UserControl is nested you can bind using RelativeSource but it entails that your element is above in tree hierarchy.